# Micro Site/ Sub Site

Tags: 2011, 2013, cme

Is there a way to allow/facilitate end user to create micro site/ sub site (one/two page site) on their own on new domain?

As a developer, I will provide Schema/CT/PT for page creation to end user to create product pages and Author will be able to  create micro site and get it hosted in the any of the sub domain of existing enterprise website.

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail - what parts of this are you expecting to achieve in Tridion?

Comment: As a developer, I will provide Schema/CT/PT for page creation to end user to create product pages and Author will be able to  create micro site and get it hosted in the any of the sub domain of existing enterprise website.

Comment: Hi "New to Tridion" - this can be done with a merging of a lot of technologies, not just Tridion. For instance, adding a new URL to your DNS is not something Tridion can do. We did this in a POC last year, and was all relatively simple if you people that understand the steps necessary. In a nutshell, yes, but it's not Tridion. Tridion gives you blueprinting which solves most of the problem, but not all of it.

Comment: Try not to make a new Publication for each sub site.  I've seen this lead to hundreds of extra publications.  Also, consider adding extra publication targets as needed.

Comment: I think the benefits outweigh the work arounds. I don't see a problem with having hundreds - or even thousands - of publications that fully isolate a site

Comment: I've seen many publications frustrate small teams of centralized authors while many isolated publications work for distributed groups (typically with one language). My biggest concern would be *how* a BluePrint is used and how translation is handled.

Answer (score 3):

You can build your Tridion implementation to make it really easy for users to set up websites that inherit from a publication(s) where you've created your Schema/PT/CT etc, meaning that users can create the actual websites within the CMS.

Tridion offers a lot of publishing options, but it's possible for you to configure it in such a way that each website publishes under a 'webroot' folder on your webserver.  This means your users can actually create these websites and publish them to an external server, but you'll need a server admin to configure the mapping/pointing of the domain to the folder published by Tridion.

Whilst it's probable that an automation of this process is possible, the development and testing time is likely to be miles larger than simply having a server admin configure the name and pointing.